# jQuery animated width item overflowing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a sort of slider, which creates a bigger item when you hover it.

I've created a fiddle of the slimmed down code to show what my problem is. In the fiddle, the green item sometimes overflows to the next line, making it disappear for a short while. Is there a way to solve this, while keeping the animations synchronised?

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4aN6/)

The jQuery is as simple as:

```
jQuery('.item', '.row').hover(function(){
    curItem = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.item', '.row').stop().not(curItem).animate({
        width: '20%'
    },200);
    curItem.stop().animate({
        width: '40%'
    },200); 
});
```

With the following relevant css:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

---

Edit: Using the accepted answer, I stumbled on an extra problem. The div's in the actual code ended up with a whitespace after each div. I found the solution for that problem [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). (font-size: 0; fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/j4aN6/2/ . You can make it work with some css hacks but, i recommend using flexbox or css transitions.

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
}

.item {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Cross-browser compatibility is quite a thing in this case. I presumed display: inline-block didn't work in IE8. Turns out it does, making this a good solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
jQuery('.item', '.row').hover(function(){
    curItem = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.item', '.row').stop().not(curItem).animate({
        width: '19.90%'
    },200);
    curItem.animate({
        width: '40%'
    },200); 
});
```

Comment: I have tried that one already. But it doesn't completely solve the problem, since it sometimes still flickers (but far less often). But the main problem with this method is that it leaves a not so pretty gap of the otherwise full width graphics.

Comment: yeah thats right..
Change width of _CurItem.animate_?? make it to **39%**? I see less flickering that way

Comment: Like I said, the main problem with this method is that it leaves a not so pretty gap at the end, where it would normally be a nice full page graphic. 1% of 1000px is a visible 10px gap, and since the average screen resolution is higher than that, that means everybody will see an even bigger gap.

Comment: Check out AndreiRosca's answer then, it looks clean